# How to check if two parts of two strings are equal?

Tags: python, regex, match

I am trying to check if two cards are of the same number(but not same suit).

For example here i would like the two kings to be approved as the same

9♥   7♣   8♦  Q♠  10♣   8♠   K♦   K♥

My problem is that i havent found a way to only match the number (or string) without the suit icon.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds more like a XY poblem. A list of tuples would make your life so much easier (e.g. ``[(9,♥), (7,♣), (8,♦), ...]``)

Comment: Semes like it yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could for example just compare the first characters:

```
>>> card1 = '9♥'
>>> card2 = '9♠'
>>> card1[0] == card2[0]
True
```

Comment: Agreed. OP could split by the space character, iterate through each element in that list, and check the first character for matches.